# UIView inside of bar button item in UIToolbar won't call action

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I'm currently trying to add a [Lottie](https://lottiefiles.com/63-hamburger-arrow-transition) Animation to an `UIView`, which is located inside of an `UIToolbar`. It works fine when the animation is being called in `viewDidLoad()`. But calling `animationView.play()` inside of the view's bar button item action, won't work.

```
@IBOutlet var animationSubview: UIView!
let animationView = AnimationView(name: "hamburger")

func setupAnimation() {
        animationView.frame = CGRect(x: -33, y: -33, width: 120, height: 120)
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        animationSubview.addSubview(animationView)
}

@IBAction func buttonHamburger(_ sender: Any) {
        animationView.play()
}
```

Is there mistake inside of my code or is an `UIView` inside of a toolbar just not working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure issue is in the call?

I had a similar problem(without animation)

Maybe your button does not receive taps because of Toolbar(or something else) cancel touches.